# Netgear drivers silent install

Tags: windows-8, drivers

does anyone know how to do a silent none reboot of netgear drivers

Netgear wna3100 v2 drivers to be exact on windows 8, my batch file is working perfect for my custom install programs but i can not find any direction on how to silent switch the netgear drivers.

Comment: What format are they in? Do you have a package like .exe or .msi?

Comment: They are .exe , the /s /S -s /silent /install -install none of this is working for me, I also tried to upack the exe and extract the contents and use that for the silent install, still nothing working http://downloadcenter.netgear.com/en/Disclaimer.aspx?redirecturl=http://netgeardownload.registria.com/single_page_registration?product[sku]=wna3100&download_url=http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WNA3100/WNA3100_V2.1.0.4.zip

Comment: Well, being a .exe (installshield at that) the switches may not exist. It is up to the packager to include the switches at all, unlike in an MSI where the package is pretty universal on what switches it uses. doing `setup.exe /?` just launches the installer... So my guess is there is very limited to no command line support.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is too tech-y for you, but if you have the inf file and the hardware id, you can download and use devcon (windows sdk), which like the command-line version of device manager, like this:

```
devcon update e1k62x64.inf PCI\CC_0200
```